# Measure theoretic Notation.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I am confused with the notation in equation 1. As to me it is not making sense since $\mu_{f}(f(A))$ is a value and $d\mu_{f}(A)$ is differential (term containing in integral ) are equal.

[image: equation 1]

Comment: I think this is $d$ times the value $\mu_f(A)$. I also wonder if it should be the inverse image instead of direct image by $f$ on the left. Morally the map is $d$-to-$1$.

Comment: Yes, $d$ is the degree of the map $f.$ So $d\mu_f(A)$ is not a differential. It's just a poor choice of notation.